# How do you use the MDL color classes when the color name has two words?

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

In Material Design Lite, you can add CSS classes to a component to change either the background color or the text color:

```
mdl-color--{color-name}-{shade}
mdl-color-text--{color-name}-{shade}
```

To set a div's background color to orange you could do this:

```
<div class="mdl-color--orange">...</div>
```

Does anyone know how to do it when the color name has two words, such as *Light Blue*, *Light Green*, etc? I've tried just about every combination of dashes and underscores I could think of with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You separate them with one dash. Examples:

- [`mdl-color--light-blue-100`](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/mdl-1.x/src/palette/_palette.scss#L774)
- [`mdl-color--light-green-A100`](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/mdl-1.x/src/palette/_palette.scss#L1334)
- [`mdl-color-text--deep-orange`](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/mdl-1.x/src/palette/_palette.scss#L1852)
- [`mdl-color-text--blue-grey-700`](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/mdl-1.x/src/palette/_palette.scss#L2218)

Don't forget you need to [include them in your theme](https://getmdl.io/customize/index.html).

Comment: That did it! As far as including them in your theme, all of the colors seem to be included already.  My theme is Light Green and Orange, but all of the CSS color classes work.

Comment: That means `$trim-color-classes` is set to `false` in your `SCSS` variables. You'll probably want set it to `true` when you'll start worrying about Google Page Speed optimizations and score.

Comment: I'm using the hosted file, but that's good to know if they ever change it.